# How to set the font family I want in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to a set some text to font-family: times new roman, but I see something different in my browser (using chrome).

Relevant html code:

```
<p style="color:#F17141;font-size: 120px; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot; ; font-weight: bold;">"</p>
```

Relevant css:

```
element.style {
  color: #F17141;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Actual rendered font taken from the developer tools in browser:

```
Times New Roman—Local file(1 glyph)
```

The actual text I am getting which is not Times new roman

[image: The actual text I am getting which is not Times new roman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are declaring `font-family` is perfect. And the output it is showing in browser is also normal in case of html and it is `Times New Roman`, too. But, the quotation sign you were expecting is mainly known as curly quotes, which is unicode character but shown generally when we use it in word documents.

You see, there is difference between below three signs:

> **“ " ”**

So, when you type using keyboard, the middle one from above signs is input there. Just copy paste the curly one if you need to use it anywhere. Here's the working demonstration:

```css
p {
  color: #F17141;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>“ " ”</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as bellow (you can set `class` to `tag`):

```css
.quote{
    color: #F17141;
    font-size: 120px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<p class="quote">"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to import font family in head or css file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Times+New+Roman);
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p style="color:#F17141;font-size: 120px; font-family: Times New Roman; font-weight: bold;">Insert text here</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem `&quot;Times New Roman&quot`. Use actual quotes. If your attribute is surrounded with double quotes, use single or visa versa:

```html
<p style="color:#F17141;font-size: 120px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-weight: bold;">TNR</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add a `class` to your `<p>` element like this and then, add the `class` in your css file like this:

```css
.text{
       color: #F17141;
       font-size: 120px;
       font-family: "Times New Roman";
       font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<p class="text">place your text here</p>
```

You could also use the `<p>` tag itself, but then all `<p>` elements get the same styling. Use classes if you want a different styling for different elements

```css
p {
       color: #F17141;
       font-size: 120px;
       font-family: "Times New Roman";
       font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<p class="text">place your text here</p>
```

When using inline styling, you should do it like this (by using single quotes):

```html
<p style="color:#F17141;font-size:120px;font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-weight:bold;">place your text here</p>
```